# Angular bootstrap-select with out jquery

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-select

I am trying to implement bootstrap-select in angular.

I found https://github.com/joaoneto/angular-bootstrap-select and this works great wit jquery.

But actually i want to have plugin with out jquery dependency.

Please suggest if we have any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select) from [AngularUI](http://angular-ui.github.io/).